# Is it possible to make 7-Zip also extract all the other files when double clicking an exe?

Tags: 7-zip

With Winrar, when I double click an exe file in an archive, it also extracts all the other files in the archive, which is really handy for when the program depends on the other included files.

I want to switch to 7-zip, but I'm forced to manually extract the archive before running an exe inside it.

Is there any way to make it work like Winrar?

Comment: Do you mean recursive extraction?

Comment: No, let's say there's an archive containing "program.exe" and "required.dll" 
Suppose program.exe depends on the dll.
If I open the archive in Winrar and double click program.exe, it extracts both files to a temporary directory and successfully runs the exe.
If I open it in 7-Zip and double click program.exe, it only extracts the exe to the temp directory and the program doesn't work, since it's missing required.dll, forcing me to manually extract it first.

Comment: Why don't you use a self extracting archive ?

Comment: I'm talking about archives I download from elsewhere, not ones I create myself. Sorry for the confusion.